# Appending dynamic content directly next to an element on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I need to show a form next to an element using jQuery. It is critical that it appears directly to the right of the spot `<h3>` tag the user clicks. I have tried setting this up, and it is appending right -- however, it is posting it at the very top instead of next to the associated tag.

The first component is my view, where I am showing a blog post. Next to it, I want to display a form that will allow users to comment. This comment box has a class `exampleToggle`, and I am going to hide it with my jQuery until the users clicks a part of the page.

**myview.html.erb**

```
<div class="special">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
                <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
                <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
        <% end %>
    </div>

<div class="exampleToggle">
        <%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :post %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5 id="username">Username</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%= f.hidden_field :slug, :id => "hiddenPicker"%>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

It's critical that when the user clicks on the `h3` tag, the comment form appears directly right of the clicked element (think of a long post where the user scrolls down). To do this, I am using some jQuery to `append` the box and also fill in some data in a `hidden_field`:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.exampleToggle').hide();
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $("h3").click(function(){
             $('.exampleToggle').show();
             $(this).append(whatever);
              $("form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
            });
        });

    $(function () {
        $('h3').on('click', function (){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input#hiddenPicker').val(id);
        });
    });

</script>
```

All of this works when it is run locally with one exception: the `exampleToggle` comment form appends to the very top right of the post, no matter how far down on the page it is being clicked from.

Any ideas on why append isn't working here?

Also, in case it helps, here's some CSS that is being used for that class:

```
.exampleToggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 4%;
  background-color: white;
  left: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

div .exampleToggle {
    border: 9px solid #002b52;
    height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}

div .exampleToggle:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 22px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

Comment: Good question. I have tried using `.after()` and `.prepend()`, but both are running into the same problem: posting the div to the very top.

Comment: `.after()` is the method you need to make the new element an adjacent sibling of the existing one. If it's displaying it in the wrong place then either you are adding it after the wrong element, or there's a problem with your CSS. I'd suggest temporarily hardcoding the required element in your html so that you can experiment with the CSS.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

Comment: I notice you have the class set to `position: absolute; top: 0;` - that would explain why it always appears at the top of its parent even when you insert it `.after()` its associated `<h3>`. (Also, there are no `<h3>` elements in the markup that you show - I'm not sure how much CSS help we can give you for elements that you don't show.)